# Multilevel Subdomain htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a multilevel subdomain redirect using htaccess.  i.e.  http://jon.doe.example.com/?number=120384  redirects to http://www.example.com/lookup.php?firstname=joe&lastname=doe&number=120384

Here is what I have tried, but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).example.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ /lookup.php?firstname=%1&lastname=%2&%{QUERY_STRING} [P,L,QSA]
```

When I call http://jon.doe.example.com/?number=120384 it just redirects to www.example.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify the code in .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/\?number=(.*)$ /lookup.php?firstname=%1&lastname=%2&number=$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Here the second level subdomain will be extracted in the parameter `%1`, the first level subdomain in `%2`. The value of the query string parameter number will be available in $1.